# Selecting the next link using XPath

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, html-parsing

I have to write an XPath expression to get the href attribute of the anchor tag in the html bellow that comes right after the one that is marked as "current-page" (in the example #notimportant/2).

```
<dd>
    <a href="#notimportant/1" class="current-page">1</a>
    <a href="#notimportant/2">2</a>
    <a href="#notimportant/3">3</a>
    <a href="#notimportant/4">4</a>
    <!-- EDIT: Do not return the next sibling if @href ends with /last -->
    <a href="#notimportant/last">last</a>
</dd>
```

I thought about starting with something like //a[@class='current-page']/../next-sibling-of-first-node/@href but I am stuck here...

Could anyone help me with this one? I have googled around but XPath is not my favorite skill (and no, I can't use jQuery. it is not a webapp).

Comment: What do you mean return empty?  If there is no following sibling, it will ordinarily return null.

Comment: Sorry, you can see how I am an XPath noob. 
I just want to return the next element if its href does not end with "/last". Otherwise I would like the expression to return null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//a[@class='current-page']/following-sibling::a[1]
```

Comment: Guys, you are too fast for me. :-P

Comment: Thanks guys. That was super fast. I have edited my question, would you mind reviewing the answer?